# Minimal working example with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am struggling with a simple stupid MWE using `pgfplots`. The goal is just read and simple draw data from external file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The `data.dat` is located in the same folder and it has the most simple structure:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I get: **! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the requested column number '1' in table 'data.dat' does not exist!? Please verify you used the correct index 0 <= i < N..**

What is the problem?

Comment: You need both x and y, but you only have one column!

Comment: As JPi said, by *default* you need 2 data columns. Of course you can also use only one data column, but then you have to provide the "other" column in a different way, e.g. by "calculating" it as e.g. `y expr=\thisrowno{0}*2`.

Comment: You can use the following syntax: `\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0]`. See section 4.3.2 of the `pgfplots` package documentation.